# How to generate foreground-only image given the foreground silhouette in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, background, foreground, subtraction

I did the background substraction part for my foreground extraction task. Now that i have silhouette representing foreground in white and background in black, I dont know how to make a foreground image containing only the pixels values (from the original frame). I am using Opencv 2.3 and i am using Mat for storing images. Any ideas?
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do as follow:

```
Mat image; // the original image

Mat foreground_bw; // the foreground in black and white
background_subtractor ( image, foreground_bw, -1.0 );

// getting the corresponding pixel values for the foreground.
Mat foreground = Mat::zeros ( image.rows, image.cols, image.type() );
image.copyTo ( foreground, foreground_bw );
```

Answer (score 1):

make a new image with the dimensions of the original, cycle through all the pixels in the background / foreground image (the one where background is black and foreground white) and for each pixel either copy from the current / original image (the one from the camera etc) or from your background estimate. done.